# DLL function signature in VB

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, pinvoke

I need to call a DLL function from a VB application. The function is declared as

```cpp
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) int Average(HBITMAP SrcHandle, HBITMAP DstHandle)
```

in the DLL, which is written in C++.

I can call it seamlessly in a C# program, with the declaration

```cs
[DllImport("Integrate.dll")]
public static extern int Average(IntPtr SrcHandle, IntPtr DstHandle);
```

Then in VB am trying

```vb
Declare Function Average Lib "Integrate.dll" _
   (ByVal SrcHandle As IntPtr, ByVal DstHandle As IntPtr) As Integer
```

This compiles but unfortunately at run-time I get the following **error** message:

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected Message: A call to PInvoke function
>   'TestVB!WindowsApplication1.Form1::Average' has unbalanced the stack.
>   This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match
>   the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and
>   parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged
>   signature.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't use the **Declare** keyword, this is VB6 style. Now the **System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport** Attribute for the function is for interrest

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, as is so often the case, a mis-match of calling convention. The C code uses cdecl, the VB code uses stdcall. You need to specify the calling convention when you import the function, which means you need p/invoke.

```
<DllImport("Integrate.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Shared Function Average(ByVal SrcHandle As IntPtr, _
    ByVal DstHandle As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

Note that your C# code is also wrong, for the same reason. It should be:

```
[DllImport("Integrate.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Average(IntPtr SrcHandle, IntPtr DstHandle);
```

I can only imagine that your C# project has the PInvokeStackImbalance MDA disabled.

Comment: @GSerg Presumably the C# project has the PInvokeStackImbalance  MDA disabled. After all, the C# and VB code in the question are equivalent as I am sure you can see.

Comment: The C# project works like charm, both 32 and 64 bits. After specifying the Cdecl convention, the error condition has disappeared in VB. But the arguments are swapped !?!

Comment: In the end, it seems to work when specifying the calling convention to VB, and I was wrong, the arguments aren't swapped. The convention seems to be the default under C#, there is no need to specify it. Thanks.

Comment: No. Same default in C# as VB. Stdcall. Easily verified. You C# code is wrong. My answer is accurate.

Comment: I honestly don't know what you are looking for here.

Comment: Another possible reason for no error on imbalanced stack would be the fact that it used to be silently corrected at runtime, but not anymore, and VS2010 used by the OP is [the one where the change happened](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef65cd89-d40e-400a-a9b0-3b625e3d22fe/c2010-change-in-default-call-convention-for-dllimport-for-vs2010?forum=csharplanguage).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `DllImport` attribute in VB.NET too. It is actually the native .NET way to do it. `Declare` is mostly used in older versions of VB.

```vb
<DllImport("Integrate.dll")> _
Public Shared Function Average(ByVal SrcHandle As IntPtr, ByVal DstHandle As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

Comment: Mh, no improvement with the newer syntax :(

Comment: @YvesDaoust : How and what are you passing to the method? The C# signature and my VB.NET are the same, so it should work if it does in C#. -- Also, if you set up two equal examples in C# and VB.NET, does it only work in C#?

Comment: Nothing exotic:             IntPtr Handle1 = ((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).GetHbitmap();
            IntPtr Handle2 = ((Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image).GetHbitmap();
            int Error = Average(Handle2, Handle2);

Comment: Dim Src As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image
        Dim Dst As Bitmap = PictureBox2.Image
        Dim SrcHandle As IntPtr = Src.GetHbitmap()
        Dim DstHandle As IntPtr = Dst.GetHbitmap()
        Dim Ret As Integer = Average(SrcHandle, DstHandle)

Comment: Part of the mystery is uncovered. The DLL was compiled for 32 bits but was referring to some 64 bits DLLs (don't ask me why). This didn't seem to trouble C#, but VB didn't like it. I have rebuilt all for 64 bits and the problem is gone.

Comment: That doesn't sound remotely plausible. You'd get a completely different error message. The real issue is your calling convention being wrong.

Comment: And clearly switching to 64 bit is going to resolve PInvokeStackImbalance, because it is not implemented on x64!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: things are as I describe. The 64 bits call is working. The 32 bits DLL works with C# but not with VB, with the given error message.

Comment: The error message is because of the erroneous calling convention. If your 32 bit program attempted to load 64 bit DLLs then the error would be very different. You would not get as far as being able to call the function because the DLL would not have loaded in the first place.  And for sure you don't get the MDA under 64 bits because it doesn't exist under 64 bits. On the other hand, it sounds as though you've already made up your mind. Which is fine. Perhaps you are right and I am talking nonsense, and you don't need help any more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: my DLL is 32 bits but DependencyWalker reports that it is linked against some 64 bits DLL. That's the only difference I see that could explain the behavior with C#/VB 32/64.

Comment: That's erroneous output from Dependency Walker. You are probably using the 64 bit version. Use the 32 bit version. Anyway, I happen to know what I am talking about here. I've told you repeatedly that the stack imbalance MDA does not exist on x64, but still you doubt that. It's clearly documented so. Everything I have said so far is accurate. Take it or leave it.